# Linux Fedora Core 18 freezes on OpenSSH login

Tags: ssh, fedora, login, openssh

```
miagos:~ $ uname -a
Linux miagos 3.9.6-200.fc18.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 13 18:56:55 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a reproducible issue, when my desktop Linux node stays online for more than ~24 hours and any attempt to `ssh` or `scp` login, the node just freezes..  no response at all, keyboard, mouse, IP stack halted, no ping response etc.. all frozen and requires a hard reboot.

This only happens anytime after ~24 hours uptime; after a reboot there is no login issue.

After reboot, around ~24 hours later, `ssh` will ask for my password and only after inputting correct password (attempting to spawn a shell) the machine locks up, a failed password re-asks as normal and an SSH session that does not open a terminal (strictly for Dynamic forwarding) works without lockup within the bug period.

Now I really want to know how to place the node in some type of DEBUG (Kernel or Openssh?) setting to get a clue as the logs (via `journalctl`) doesn't display anything useful before lockup.

Comment: You start the machine, and when you try to ssh to it, it freezes? Sure that it is running before the ssh attempt? Open a terminal (a VT would probably be best), run a `tail -f /var/log/messages` in it, try to `ssh` in and see what the last lines are. That might give a clue.

Comment: Fedora 18 is end-of-life (or shortly before). consider upgrading.

Comment: Doesn't freeze initially, only after ~24hours uptime, Ok I will place the sshd server in DEBUG mode and try logging in during the bug period.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, out of all my Linux nodes..this Fedora machine is the only one with this setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
```

I have changed this to and cycled the sshd daemon

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
```

And no lockups at all this past week after ssh login..